# Algorithm to estimate aggregated outcome variable

Tags: r, regression, algorithms, weighted-regression

I am looking for an algorithm that can estimate weights for an aggregated weighted average. The difficulty is that my outcome variable is an aggregated group variable.

I have the following data that could train an algorithm:
There are N groups. Say, for each group there are 3 observations that each makes up one row. Each row includes y* and n explanatory variables. For each group, there is an outcome variable y. The following table gives an example of the data:

```
+------+----+---------------+-----+---------------+-------+
|  y   | y* | Explanatory 1 | ... | Explanatory n | Group |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      | 3  |        1      | ... |      500      |   1   |
+      ---------------------------------------------------+
|      | 3  |        0      | ... |      1214     |   1   |
+      ---------------------------------------------------+
| 4.25 | 5  |        1      | ... |      71       |   1   |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|      | 3  |        1      | ... |      23       |   2   |
+      ---------------------------------------------------+
|      | 2  |        1      | ... |      821      |   2   |
+      ---------------------------------------------------+
| 2.00 | 2  |        1      | ... |      200      |   2   |
----------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I had an outcome variable y for each row, I could use a multivariate regression algorithm. Instead, y is a weighted average of all rows of the group. The explanatory variables make up a weight (which is unknown) for y*:

w<sub>ij</sub> y*<sub>ij</sub> = (ß1*Explanatory 1<sub>ij</sub> + ... + ßn*Explanatory n<sub>ij</sub>) y<sub>ij</sub>*

with index i denoting the group and j the row. The outcome variable y<sub>i</sub> then is the sum of the weighted y<sub>ij</sub>* for all rows of the group.

y<sub>i</sub> = ∑<sub>1</sub><sup>3</sup>(w<sub>ij</sub> y<sub>ij</sub>*)/ N

I am now looking for an algorithm that is able to estimate the weight given the outcome variable y, such that I can estimate a ŷ for each row that takes all observations from preceding rows into account.

This is my first question on StackOverflow. If you have any ideas, how I could clarify my question, please let me know.
Similarly, I am totally new to working with algorithms. All hints are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let me change your notation somewhat:

z = w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x3. The xi are your y*, the wi are the weights.

wi = sum( aij yj ) over j. The yj are the explaining vars.

Then you get

z = sum( wi xi ) = sum( sum( aij yj ) xi ) = sum( aij xi yj ).

So use multivariate regression to estimate the aij. Then use the formula above to estimate the wi.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik4 for answering so quickly! I will try that out!